# How to compare two uploaded images using php

Tags: php, ajax, image, file

Assume that I have two image upload forms.I just want to identify whether the images uploaded are same or not.How can I handle that in my action.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate file's md5 hash and compare.

```
if(md5_file(/var/path/to/file1.jpg)!=md5_file(/var/path/to/file2.jpg)){
//do the dew
}
```

References: http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php